# Returns (bool) check in function

Tags: solidity

I've seen many functions using a returns (bool). What does it do? What can it be used for?

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
```

Comment: It's the return value for that specific function. It can be used for control flow or any kind of logic purpose in the caller code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns a boolean value, ie *true* or *false*.

Assuming you are reading from a token spec, that *transferFrom* function most likely should return *true* if the transfer is made successfully, and *false* if it fails.

Comment: How can a transfer fail?

Comment: This very much depends on what else is going on in your contract, but one reason which probably applies to your contract would be if the balance of the `from` account is less than the `value` that needs to be transferred. So you would have something like `require(value <= balance)` at the start of the function, where `balance` is a variable with the `from` account's balance of this token.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure that I have the same angle for that question. I asked myself if it's a good practice to return a `true` value on a function success.

Many see that pattern first in the ERC20 standard, the transfer function for example:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success)
```

But the ERC20 is pretty old (it was defined in 2015). The security practices nowadays favour `require/assert` that test a condition and revert the transaction if the condition isn't met. That's the style of coding that newer standards like [ERC721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) are using. When a transaction is reverted no value is actually returned. Like raising an Exception in most programming languages.

If we look into [openzepeplin implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) of ERC20:

```
function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value) internal {
    require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

    _balances[from] = _balances[from].sub(value);
    _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(value);
    emit Transfer(from, to, value);
}

function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    _transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
    return true;
}
```

We see that if the method succeeds `true` would be returned, otherwise the transaction will be reverted and no value will be returned at all. So it looks like `boolean` is returned for mere compatibility with the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain with one easy example.

```
contract A{
    bool public checkvalue;
function transferFrom(uint256 value)
    private 
    returns(bool){
    //.... any logical part here
    //let us consider simple example as below
        if (value == 2) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    function check()public{
        //...your logical part here 
        checkvalue = transferFrom(2);
    }
}
```

If you have knowledge on other any programming language like c,java then it is also same **bool**ean in there. Here , check() function calls the transferFrom() function and return the boolean value **true or false** . Another Practical example is - If you do not need any return value on execution but you have to confirm it works and return as true and if not full fill the logical part on execution then return false. Hope, it might help you.

Comment: But how can a transfer fail? Aside of out of gas.

Comment: there might be many reasons and depends on what logic you have implemented, let see, if  (from_address !=msg.sender) return false. this is also another reasons.

Answer (score 1):

returns(bool) - means return "true" or "false". For instance, if your transfer went through, you could write in your argument "return true". Or if it fails, "return false".